# how pvc decide which pv to bound in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I am create a pv in kubernetes v1.16.0 cluster like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: nfs-flink-pv1
  namespace: middleware
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  nfs:
    server: "192.168.64.251"
    path: "/mnt/data/flink"
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
```

and create pvc like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: flink-pv-claim
  namespace: middleware
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
```

what is the according about pvc bound to pv? the storage size? how to make pvc bound to specify pv?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#binding) a PVC is bound to a PV which has got enough capacity to satisfy the PV.

Also claims can specify a label selector to further filter the set of volumes. Only the volumes whose labels match the selector can be bound to the claim. This is documented [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#selector)